# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' Python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pycharm

I am working on the face compared to python. I am using below source code for that task. I am stuck with this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' Could you please anyone guide me to solve this issue?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/web/predict', methods=['POST'])
def web_predict():
    image1 = request.files.get('image1').read()
    image2 = request.files.get('image2').read()

    result = process(image1, image2)
    result = Markup(json2html.convert(result))
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

Comment: `request.files.get('somefile')` is not actually returning you the object type you expect. I.E its not finding the file so you get a `None` object. and `None` objects dont have a read method

Comment: Try to print ```request.files``` object to see if the images is in request

Comment: First check whether the images is in request,so do like if "image1" in request.Files: and then print (request.Files["image1"] ,image1= request.Files["image1]